# c#, убрать дублирование if

Tags: c#, winforms

Метод определяет вложен ли один прямоугольник в другой и выводит  номер (с нуля) внутреннего.
Иначе возвращает `-1`. Если прямоугольники совпадают, можно вернуть номер любого из них.

Как убрать дублирование кода?

```
public static int IndexOfInnerRectangle(Rectangle r1, Rectangle r2)
{
    if (r1.Left <= r2.Left && r1.Right >= r2.Right && r1.Top <= r2.Top && r1.Bottom >= r2.Bottom)
        return 1;
    else if (r1.Left >= r2.Left && r1.Right <= r2.Right && r1.Top >= r2.Top && r1.Bottom <= r2.Bottom)
        return 0;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

Comment: Где дублирование?

Comment: @AzizUmarov в логических выражениях

Comment: [Rectangle.Contains](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rectangle.contains?view=net-5.0#System_Drawing_Rectangle_Contains_System_Drawing_Rectangle_)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Например вот так

```cs
public static int IndexOfInnerRectangle(Rectangle r1, Rectangle r2)
{
    if (IsInner(r2, r1))
        return 1;
    if (IsInner(r1, r2))
        return 0;
    return -1;
}

private static bool IsInner(Rectangle r1, Rectangle r2)
{
    return r1.Left >= r2.Left && r1.Right <= r2.Right && r1.Top >= r2.Top && r1.Bottom <= r2.Bottom;
}
```

Можно даже основной метод записать с помощью двух тернарных операторов

```cs
public static int IndexOfInnerRectangle(Rectangle r1, Rectangle r2)
{
    return IsInner(r2, r1) ? 1 : IsInner(r1, r2) ? 0 : -1;
}
```

И синтаксически оба метода можно записать в форме выражения

```cs
public static int IndexOfInnerRectangle(Rectangle r1, Rectangle r2)
    => IsInner(r2, r1) ? 1 : IsInner(r1, r2) ? 0 : -1;

private static bool IsInner(Rectangle r1, Rectangle r2)
    => r1.Left >= r2.Left && r1.Right <= r2.Right && r1.Top >= r2.Top && r1.Bottom <= r2.Bottom;
```

Но eсть [еще способ](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rectangle.contains?view=net-5.0) - `Rectangle.Contains`, встроенный метод. Спасибо @AlexanderPetrov за подсказку. Я когда готовил ответ, искал что-то подобное, но не нашел.

```cs
public static int IndexOfInnerRectangle(Rectangle r1, Rectangle r2)
    => r2.Contains(r1) ? 1 : r1.Contains(r2) ? 0 : -1;
```

Answer (score 2):

@aepot предложил лучшее решение (за которое я тоже проголосовал),
однако если бы дело касалось не прямоугольников, а какой-то другой логики я бы сократил так:

```
public static int IndexOfInnerRectangle(Rectangle r1, Rectangle r2)
{
    int q = r1.Left <= r2.Left ? 1 : 0;
    q += r1.Right >= r2.Right ? 1 : 0;
    q += r1.Top <= r2.Top ? 1 : 0;
    q += r1.Bottom >= r2.Bottom ? 1 : 0;

    if ( q == 4) 
        return 1;
    else if (q == 0)
        return 0;
    return -1;
}
```

вариант для ретурна по `таблице истинности` тогда условия не нужны:

```
return [0,-1,-1,-1, 1][q]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

иногда  так можно сократить код